# DS3400 - Getting exact operation progress

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, ibm

Ended up adding a disk to a DS3400 array. Unfortunately it's been going for nearly 3 days now.

Is there a way through CLI or otherwise that I can actually see what the completed percentage is?

Thank you.

Comment: How large is the existing array? I'm guessing its using RAID5

Answer (score 2):

Have you got the [IBM DS Storage Manager software](http://www-947.ibm.com/systems/support/supportsite.wss/selectproduct?brandind=5000028&familyind=5348409&osind=0&oldbrand=5000028&oldfamily=5348409&oldtype=0&taskind=2&matrix=Y&psid=ap&continue.x=15&continue.y=17) installed? That's used to manage the IBM DS disk systems, and shows a progress bar during an array rebuild.
It works just fine with our DS4300.

Comment: unfortunately not the case with the 3400.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can query the progress using the `SMcli` command line utility:

```
SMcli -n <subsystemName> show logicalDrive [“<logicalDriveName>”] actionProgress;
```

Which should return something along the lines of:

```
Logical Drive logicalDriveName
Action: Reconstruction
Percent Complete: 74%
```

References: *IBM System Storage DS3000, DS4000, and DS5000: Command Line Interface and Script Commands Programming Guide*.

Answer (score -1):

Yea you can see progress bar on DS4xxx and DS5xxx series but somehow IBM/LSI figured out that you don`t need it on DS3400...